# How to solve Error Out of present Range in Power BI (DAX formula)

Tags: string-formatting, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have tried to fix the out of present range problem in Power Bi Dax formula

**General background**

I have a data-set as below, the dashboard allows the user to select the preferred currency and then the table update the value. For example, if click on the US, then the table sum all Sales in Jan from the US

as well as **showing $ or €** accordingly

[image]

The DAX function I have tried is

```
CONCATENATE( Table[Country]="US", "$",FORMAT(sum(Table[Sales]),"0")
```

but it comes up with below error

> ### Couldn't load the data for this visual
>
> The following system error occurred: Out of present range

Any help, please. thanks

Comment: CONCATENATE does not take that kind of input. Only text.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/concatenate-function-dax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any concatenation. You can simply put the currency symbol in the `FORMAT` function. For example:

```
Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Country]),
              "EUR", FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "€0.00"),
              "US",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "$0.00"),
              "UK",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "£0.00"))
```